# How to apply division operation across values in a single column, based on other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a fairly large data frame with one numeric column and a bunch of factors. One of these factors has only two values. I want to generate a new, smaller data frame that divides the numeric variable by another value in the same column.

Example Data:

```
set.seed(1)

V1 <- rep(c("a","b"), each =8)
V2 <- 1:4
V3 <- rep(c("High","Low"), each=4)
V4 <- rnorm(16)

foo <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4)
```

Which gives me the following data frame:

```
   V1 V2   V3          V4
1   a  1 High -0.62645381
2   a  2 High  0.18364332
3   a  3 High -0.83562861
4   a  4 High  1.59528080
5   a  1  Low  0.32950777
6   a  2  Low -0.82046838
7   a  3  Low  0.48742905
8   a  4  Low  0.73832471
9   b  1 High  0.57578135
10  b  2 High -0.30538839
11  b  3 High  1.51178117
12  b  4 High  0.38984324
13  b  1  Low -0.62124058
14  b  2  Low -2.21469989
15  b  3  Low  1.12493092
16  b  4  Low -0.04493361
```

I want to generate a smaller data frame that divides V4(High) by the matching V4(Low)

```
   V1 V2         V4
1   a  1  -1.901181  #foo[1,4]/foo[5,4]
2   a  2  -0.223827  #foo[2,4]/foo[6,4]
...
```

The problem is my real data is messier than this. I *do* know that V3 repeats regularly, there is a High for every Low, but V2 and V1 *do not* repeat regularly like I've demonstrated here. They are not highly irregular, but there are a few dropped values (i.e. b3Low and b3High might have been dropped)

I'm assuming I'm going to have to restructure my data frame somehow, but I have no idea where to even start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `aggregate( V4 ~ V1+V2, data=foo,  function(x) x[1]/x[2])`

Comment: This is it! Thanks to everyone else, I thought it would be dplyr as well, but this is the single line that solves the problem. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `dplyr` and `reshape2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

foo %>% dcast(V1 + V2 ~ V3, value.var="V4") %>%
  mutate(Ratio = High/Low) %>%
  select(V1, V2, Ratio)

  V1 V2      Ratio
1  a  1 -1.9011807
2  a  2 -0.2238274
3  a  3 -1.7143595
4  a  4  2.1606764
5  b  1 -0.9268251
6  b  2  0.1378915
7  b  3  1.3438880
8  b  4 -8.6759832
```

Get rid of the `select` statement if you want to keep the `High` and `Low` columns in the final result.

Or with `dplyr` alone:

```
foo %>% group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  summarise(Ratio = V4[V3=="High"]/V4[V3=="Low"])
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)[ , list(Ratio = V4[V3=="High"]/V4[V3=="Low"]), by=list(V1, V2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to first `split` the dataframe by V3. Then, if they're ordered correctly, it's straightforward. If not, then merge them into a single dataframe and proceed from there. For example:

```
# Split foo
fooSplit <- split(foo, foo$V3)

#If ordered correctly (as in the example)
fooSplit[[1]]$V4 / fooSplit[[2]]$V4

# [1] -1.9011807 -0.2238274 -1.7143595  2.1606764 -0.9268251  0.1378915  1.3438880 -8.6759832

#If not ordered correctly, merge into new dataframe
#Rename variables in prep for merge

names(fooSplit[[1]])[4] <- "High"
names(fooSplit[[2]])[4] <- "Low"

#Merge into a single dataframe, drop V3
d <- merge(fooSplit[[1]][,-3], fooSplit[[2]][,-3], by = 1:2, all = TRUE)
d$High / d$Low

# [1] -1.9011807 -0.2238274 -1.7143595  2.1606764 -0.9268251  0.1378915  1.3438880 -8.6759832
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `dpyr` package could help you with that.
Following with your code:

1. You can create a "key" column to use when crossing references between "High" and "Low" values.

   ```
   foo <- mutate(foo,paste(V1,V2))  
   names(foo) <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","key")
   ```
2. Now you have the "key" column you could use **filter**, to split the data set in two groups ("High" and "Low"), **merge** to join them using the "key column and **select** to tide up the data set and just keep the important columns.

   ```
   foo <- select(merge(filter(foo,V3=="High"), filter(foo,V3=="Low"), 
                                            by="key"), V1.x, V2.x, V4.x, V4.y)
   ```
3. At last, when you have the data on the same table, you could create a new calculated column using **mutate**. We use **select** again to keep the data set as simple as possible.

   ```
   foo <- select(mutate(foo,V4.x/V4.y,name="V4"),1,2,5)
   ```

So, if you execute:

```
foo <- mutate(foo,paste(V1,V2))  
names(foo) <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","key")   
foo <- select(merge(filter(foo,V3=="High"), filter(foo,V3=="Low"), 
                                       by="key"), V1.x, V2.x, V4.x, V4.y)  
foo <- select(mutate(foo,V4.x/V4.y,name="V4"),1,2,5)
```

you will get:

```
#  V1.x V2.x  V4.x/V4.y
#1    a    1 -1.9011807
#2    a    2 -0.2238274
#3    a    3 -1.7143595
#4    a    4  2.1606764
#5    b    1 -0.9268251
#6    b    2  0.1378915
#7    b    3  1.3438880
#8    b    4 -8.6759832
```

Probably it´s not shortest way to do it but I hope it will help you.